# KRB5 preauthentication failed

Tags: 20.04, authentication, kerberos

I try to authenticate on a Ubuntu 20.04 server joined to a Windows 2012 R2 AD domain, but it fails with "Preauthentication failed" errors. I have configured the Ubuntu server the same way I did for another Ubuntu server (but with version 18.04) joined to the same domain and for which I authenticate successfully with the same account.
Has anybody any idea?

Comment: Do you have the ssh server (I assume you are using ssh) joined to the AD correctly? Does it have corresponding host service principle names in AD and in krb5.keytab?

Comment: Yes, I think the server is joined to the AD correctly. Where can I check the host SPN in AD and how can I open the krb5.keytab file correctly to check its content?